# MAX() and GROUP BY, need COUNT(*) of whole result

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

I have a `SELECT` query I'm executing which has a `MAX()` column and a `GROUP BY` clause, and in addition to the results of this query that I need to return to the client, I also need to return the total count of all results as well.

Essentially my query is this:

```
SELECT unique_id, col1, col2, MAX(col3) as col3
FROM tbl
GROUP BY col1, col2
```

It'll usually have a `WHERE` clause too.

The `unique_id` is the primary key of the table.

When returning this data to the client, I also specify `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` clauses to limit the number of results being retrieved at one time. My problem is that I also need to display the total count of results that the above query would produce if it didn't have the `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` clauses, so that the client can later/incrementally retrieve the rest.

I know I can easily use a `WITH` temporary table to get what I want:

```
WITH temp AS (
    SELECT unique_id, col1, col2, MAX(col3) as col3
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY col1, col2
)
SELECT count(*) FROM temp
```

But I'm concerned about the efficiency of this. The sans-`LIMIT`-and-`OFFSET` query could return tens of thousands of rows, so I'm thinking that the `WITH` approach to getting the total count isn't the best way to do this.

Is there a more efficient way, which I'm not thinking of? Or is the `WITH` method the fine (e.g. is the MySQL server "smart" enough to not allocate the entire result set of the query to get the count)?

---

#### Example data

Assume this is the data in my table:

```
unique_id  col1  col2  col3
___________________________
1          5     8     30
2          5     8     33
3          5     9     40
4          6     8     30
5          6     8     31
6          6     8     32
7          6     9     39
8          7     8     33
9          7     8     32
10         8     8     34
```

So my `SELECT` query would return this (assume the client specified `LIMIT 4 OFFSET 0`):

```
SELECT unique_id, col1, col2, max(col3) as col3
FROM tbl
GROUP BY col1, col2
LIMIT 4
OFFSET 0;
    unique_id  col1  col2  col3
    ___________________________
    2          5     8     33
    3          5     9     40
    6          6     8     32
    7          6     9     39
```

And then I'd use that query *without* the `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` clauses as a subquery and `SELECT COUNT(*)` from it, which would return `6`, and I'd return both the `6` and the results to the client.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @GordonLinoff MySQL 8

Comment: You are not grouping by `unique_id` yet you are returning it. MySQL does have a mode that allows you to select non-GROUP BY columns as non-aggregated but that still doesn't mean it's a good idea to use it for what you are doing here. You can't reliably predict which `unique_id` will be returned in this case, so why return it in the first place?

Comment: Looks like you need the maximum `col3` for each `col1` and `col2` and also want the `uniqe_id` that has these 3 values. Do you confirm?

Comment: @AndriyM I see what you mean. The only reason we return the `unique_id` to the GUI is so that we can _maybe_ reference it later, and since we're grouping, the specific `unique_id` of the group that gets returned, while indeed unpredictable, isn't really that important. As long as we can reference one of them, we can reference the whole group.

Comment: @RobertKock That's correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL 8 has introduced support for [**window functions**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html), including window aggregate functions. Window aggregate functions allow you to return aggregated results alongside non-aggregated data. Basically, you can turn a regular aggregate function into a window aggregate function by attaching an `OVER` clause to it, but there are often additional options that you may need to specify, which is explained in detail in the linked manual.

You can use window aggregate functions in `GROUP BY` queries too. In those cases the window aggregate functions will apply to the row sets after the grouping is done. Note also that adding `LIMIT` will not affect the result of a window aggregate function.

Taking all the above into account, you can modify the original query like this:

```
SELECT
  unique_id,
  col1,
  col2,
  MAX(col3) as col3,
  COUNT(*) OVER () AS TotalRows
FROM
  tbl
GROUP BY
  col1,
  col2
LIMIT
  4 OFFSET 0
;
```

and get the original detail data together with the number of rows **in one go**. The `OVER` clause has no additional subclauses, which means it applies to the entire rowset.

As I have said, a window aggregate function will disregard the `LIMIT` clause, if one is attached to the query. Therefore, the `TotalRows` column above will reflect the number of rows as though the limit were not applied.

Comment: Awesome, that works perfectly. And the `EXPLAIN` output is exactly the same, so there's no loss of efficiency, except the additional memory of the extra integer column in the result set.